# how to placed three dropdown option next to each other

Tags: html, css

How do I place all three dropdown options next to each other?

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <select class="form-control" id ="numberRooms">
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
       <option value="5">5</option>
       <option value="6">6</option>
       <option value="7">7</option>
       <option value="8">8</option>
       <option value="9">9</option>
       <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    <select id="numberBeds">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="Year" id="year">
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option selected value="2011">2011</option>
    </select>                    
</div>
```

[image: i m adding a image for sample purpose]

I'm not able to place the three dropdowns next to each other. Each dropdown should touch each other and should be close to each other. I would like to do it using `css3`. How do I place all three dropdowns option next to each other?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the gap between them with font-size: 0, since they are separated by newline char

```css
#nogap {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="nogap" class="form-group col-md-6">
  <select class="form-control" id="numberRooms">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
  <select id="numberBeds">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <select name="Year" id="year">
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option selected value="2011">2011</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: ....i have form-group to textbox ....it will conflict wiith textbox. can u try using id of select or give id to div

Comment: sure, i added an id to that div

Comment: i want to apply class= "form-control" to select option and should not disturb the size of dropdown or alignment

Comment: i dont understand what your trying to do